# How to read xml file and create tree view in android

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, treeview

I always get solution of critical problems from Stack Overflow. Firstly I want to thank all the team members of SO. My problem is that I have and XML file beside the android. I want that android read this file and create tree from this file and the tree view follow testing condition of pass and fail. How can I read xml file and create tree from it. Kindly guide and help.

The xml file is created on notepad. The content of this xml file is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Parent Node name="Unit Testing" result="Passed">

  <Child Node name="GetCampaignTestclass" result="" methodName="">

    <Sub Child Node name="CampaignPageShouldNotBeNull" result="Failed" methodName="GetCampaignPages"></Sub Child Node>
    <Sub Child Node name="CampaignServiceObjectShouldNotBeNull" result="Passed" methodName="GetCampaignService"></Child Node>
  </Sub Child Node>


  <Child Node name="GetAdGroupTestclass" result="" methodName="">

    <Sub Child Node name="AdGroupPageShouldNotBeNull" result="Failed" methodName="GetAdGroupPages"></Sub Child Node>
    <Sub Child Node name="AdGroupServiceObjectShouldNotBeNull" result="Passed" methodName="GetAdGroupService"></Sub Child Node>
  </Sub Child Node>

  <Child Node name="GetTextAdTestclass" result="" methodName="">
    <Sub Child Node name="AdGroupAdPageShouldNotBeNull" result="Failed" methodName="GetTextAdPages"></Sub Child Node>
    <Sub Child Node name="AdGroupServiceObjectShouldNotBeNull" result="Passed" methodName="GetTextAdService"></Sub Child Node>
  </Sub Child Node>

  <Child Node name="GetKeywordsTestclass" result="" methodName="">
    <Sub Child Node name="AdGroupCriterionPageShouldNotBeNull" result="Failed" methodName="GetAdGroupCriterionPages"></Sub Child Node>
    <Sub Child Node name="AdGroupCriterionServiceObjectShouldNotBeNull" result="Passed" methodName="GetAdGroupCriterionService"></Sub Child Node>
  </Sub Child Node>

</Parent Node>
```

Can I make this xml file in android and read node data from it? How?

Comment: That's one badly-described xml, if I've ever seen one...

Comment: You could change "Node" to the name you're declaring." for instance, the first "Node" would be "<UnitTesting result="Passed">". But I don't know your business rules, so this may be impossible... But it's just a suggestion to make it "feel" better.